# select by order

Tags: mysql

Thare are two tables: image and car. They are linked by one-to-many unidirectional relationship.
I want to make something like gallery: simultaneously load only one photo of a car, and other photos are available via links [1], [2], [3], ...

**Question**: but how can I pull photo by it order. It means I don't know image's ids (they may be 10, 23, ....) and/ for example, I don't know which image I should pull via [3] link.

**P.S**. I pull images via command: `SELECT * FROM image WHERE car_id_fk=?`

Comment: if you are not using ORDER BY, how can you know which is the first image, and which is the third? SQL tables have no default order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use limit - keep the second number at 1, and for the first number put the selected link - 1

```
select * from image where card_id_fk=? limit 0,1
```